# Fitting an integral function given data points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting

I have a set of measures of the resistivity of a given material at different thicknesses and I'm trying to fit them using the Fuchs-Sondheimer model. My code is:

```
data = {{8.1, 60.166323}, {8.5, 47.01784}, {14, 52.534961}, {15, 
   50.4681111501753}, {20, 39.0704975714401}, {30, 
   29.7737879177201}, {45, 22.4406}, {50, 15.2659673601299}, {54, 
   18.189933218482}, {73, 14.8377093467966}, {100, 
   15.249523361101}, {137, 15.249523361101}, {170, 
   10.7190970441753}, {202, 15.249523361101}, {230, 10.9744085456615}}

G[d_, l_, p_] := NIntegrate[(y^(-3) - y^(-5)) (1 - Exp[-yd/l])/(1 - pExp[-yd/l]), {y,0.01, 1000}];

nlm  = NonlinearModelFit[data, 1/(1 - (3 l/(2 d)) G [d, l, p]) , {{l, 1}, {p, 0.5}}, d, Method -> NMinimize]
```

However it returns me these errors:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand ((1-E^(-(yd/l))) (-(1/y^5)+1/y^3))/(1-pExp[-(yd/l)]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.01,1000}}.
```

```
NonLinearModelFit: the function value is not a real number at {l,p} = {1.685382536132558,1.3465817935419881}.
```

I think that the problem is in the way in which I defined the integral function G[d, l, p], because I had to fit a different set of data points with a different function of only one variable which I defined through the NIntegrate function and it gave me no error.
Could anyone please help me?

I modified it in this way:

```
G[d_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(y^(-3) - y^(-5)) (1 - Exp[-y (d)/l])/(1 - (p) Exp[-y (d)/l]), {y, 0.01, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, MaxRecursion -> 500];
```

and now the only error is:

```
NMinimize: the function value is not a number at {l,p} = {1.685382536132558,1.3465817935419881}.
```

Comment: If it really isn't your function that's the problem, then you need better starting values.  Using the starting values you have in `NonlinearModelFit` and the minimum and maximum values of `d`, I get large negative numbers:  -5.6261*10^6 and -2.43745*10^7, respectively.